# how to create an object from number enum in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have one enum that I would like to do reverse mapping so eventually I have one object with key as enum.value and value as enum's key I can hardcode all key-value pair but how can I write something more dynamic?

```
export declare enum SAMPLE {
  AIR = 0,
  EARTH = 1,
  WATER = 2
}

REVERSESAMPLE {
SAMPLE.AIR = 'Air',
SAMPLE.EARTH = 'Earth',
SAMPLE.WATER = 'Water',

}
```

Comment: Numeric enums already have a [reverse mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings), does that not suffice?  If not, please consider [edit]ing the question to make it the issue explicit.  Also note though that `"AIR"` and `"Air"` are different strings; is that case difference intentional or a typo?  Are you intending to `declare` the enum instead of actually emitting it?  If so, how does it work?

Comment: yes, it is intentional or different case and declare. so I have to to SAMPLE enum from other file and the based on the type value from the object {type: 1} I have i need to return the string 'Earth'. however for some reason the i get `undefined` from SAMPLE[Object.type]

Comment: I’m sorry, I really don’t understand that at all .  Your sentences don’t make sense to me.  Could you try to rephrase? I imagine that you might not be a native speaker of English, but I can’t help if I don’t understand you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do this.
Sample[0] => "Air"
And Sample.Air => 0