# getting undefined from enum as unexpected from number enum in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have one object with `type` as key and 0, 1, 2 integer as value and have a number enum that I would like to get key based on type value from obj. However the result is not as i expected. anyone may know why?

```
export declare enum SAMPLE {
  AIR = 0,
  EARTH = 1,
  WATER = 2
}

const obj = [{type: 0}, {type: 2}]

obj.map(({type}: {type: number}) => SAMPLE[type])
// expected ['AIR', 'WATER']; actual [undefined, undefined]
```

Comment: You've got some mismatched parentheses and brackets in the map callback there... is that what's causing your issue?

Comment: After fixing syntax errors, seems like the issue is related to your usage of the `declare` keyword. Take a look at the thread below, but from what I gather `declare` is not needed in this situation.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43335962/purpose-of-declare-keyword-in-typescript

Comment: Yes unfortunately, no way for me to update declare it's from 3rd package

Comment: Is this question a duplicate of [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71430818/2887218)?  You mention something about `undefined` in a comment.  If so, please delete one of these questions.  Make sure any code in your question is a [mre] without unrelated issues.  The code here has weird parentheses issues (your callback is claiming to *return* a value of type `{type: number}` instead of *accepting* a parameter of that type), and the optional chaining operator on `obj?.map` is unnecessary because `obj` is definitely defined.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/wjkBlN) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: @jcalz update the problem is I cannot reproduce on playground...

Comment: If you can't tell me how to reproduce it, then I can only *guess* about what's happening.  My guess is that your runtime environment contains a `SAMPLE` value and that the `declare enum SAMPLE` is an *approximation* of that value.  A real TypeScript numeric enum would have a reverse mapping, while the one in your runtime doesn't have it.  You could possibly *patch* your runtime value like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WYvnxw).  Does that approach meet your needs? Or am I missing something?

Comment: possible to explain how this line `Object.entries(SAMPLE).forEach(([k, v]) => (SAMPLE as any)[v] = k);` is able to manually create reverse mapping?

Comment: I'm happy to explain things fully if and when I post an answer. Could you tell me first if that code works for your use cases?

Comment: yes it works. please post your answer so I can upvote it